# Repopulate Angular app data with new data from form submission from a rails api

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a rails api that sends default input to an Angular app. The angular app receives json at localhost:9000/api/query, and then the view at localhost:9000/#/query styles that json into an unordered list.

If I send a POST request (from the browser javascript debugger) to the Rails app, and can send custom input and get desired output as a json string.

```
$.get('http://rails-app-url:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my input goes here}
```

What I decided to do what build a form with an input box, and give it an ng-submit function that runs that javascript post request

```
<form ng-submit="sub()">
  <textarea name="my_input"></textarea>
  <button id="execute"></button>
</form>
```

Where the sub() function is defined in a jquery script that sets the queries variable to the desired json

```
$('#execute').click(function() {
  queries = $.get('http://url-to-rails-app:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my input here' });
});
```

to display the queries, I use markup like this

```
<div ng-controller="QueryCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="query in queries">
    <li>{{query}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

There are two problems with this:

1. the script does not execute unless it is written inline with the html for the view of this specific tab. I cannot attach it to index.html, as it can not find the #execute button.
2. even when the script is written inline with the html, the request is sent to the server, but the response from the server is not reflected in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ng-click

```
$scope.onSubmit = function() {
  queries = $http.get('http://url-to-rails-app:3000/api/query', { 'input': 'my input here' });
};

<form ng-submit="onSubmit()">
  <textarea name="my_input"></textarea>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

**EDIT**

as per comments

```
<form ng-submit="onSubmit()">
  <textarea name="my_input"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" ng-click="onSubmit()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: The rails server never actually sees the http request when I use this code.

Comment: replaced with $http... use $http rather than jquery

Comment: Even this does not apprear to be sending the request when the form is submitted... the remote server shows no activity

Comment: no log output to the console. the onSubmit function must never be running

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58178/discussion-between-johncorser-and-harishr).

Comment: wont be able to join for an hour or so... sorry

Comment: I am working on [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/7374/) without much luck. If you do get a chance to look at it, or chat in an hour, I'd be immensely grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (and use $http from AngularJS)

```
<form>
  <textarea ng-model="my_input" name="my_input"></textarea>
  <button id="execute" ng-click="sub()">Execute</button>
</form>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.sub = function(){
    $http.get('http://url-to-rails-app:3000/api/query', {'input':$scope.my_input}).success(function(data){
       $scope.queries = data;
    }
}
```

I assume that your form and your display list are in the same controller (sharing the same $scope).
Why are you using GET, I think that a POST request should be better in this case.

Comment: I probably will use post, thanks for the advice. My code still doesn't seem to work though. Can you help me out with a fiddle? I've started working in [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dakra/U3pVM/)

Comment: I don't see anything not working in the fiddle could you give me more info ?